# how to make desktop file ask for sudo password through gui

Tags: sudo, password, gui, desktop-file

I want to run an app that needs sudo to run.

I do not want to run it through terminal but through its desktop file or by clicking on a file associated with the program.

is there anyway to have it ask for sudo through gui like some system utilities do? I know muon package manager does when you want to upgrade in it.

additionally I need the sudo timeout to be kept like it is in terminal or for the password to timeout immediately so not to pose a security risk.

Comment: If the app is a GUI try: `pkexec  env DISPLAY=$DISPLAY XAUTHORITY=$XAUTHORITY appname` or if it is a background process you can use: `pkexec  appname`. If you get any error about `pkexec env ...` then see [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/332847/1086345)

Comment: what is the pkexec command what does the code snippet you gave do exactly?

Comment: pkexec command  is basically used for asking password via *gui*. However running GUI apps should fail because of lack of a `$DISPLAY` and `$XAUTHORITY`. So you have to define them in order to call correctly a GUI via sudo.

Comment: ok I tried this and it works with .desktop file. but when I double click a pcapng file, it doesnt ask for sudo and just runs wireshark as normal user.

Comment: Is the desktop file a custom desktop file? If it is, then you will have to edit the mime-type database in order to open `pcapng` files w ith your desktop file. In your pcanpng file you can use something like: **right click** -> **open file with another application** -> **search and choose your desktop file**. This can be done directly in the file manager.

Comment: Or another workaround is about editing the original desktop file for pcapng files and add the command `pkexec`. (Also you can edit some files to update the mime type database in order to include what application should open certain type of file)

Comment: thanks for this. do you know anyway to add a desktop file to the drop down menu for open file with...? not the default desktop file to use but the list of possible ones. I can search for it after selecting other applications but I would like to have it added to the default suggestions.

Comment: What operating system or (what should be better to know) what desktop environment and file manager are you using?

Comment: Btw, you can create desktop files in `/home/user/.local/share/applications` or `/usr/share/applications` directories no matter the operating system. However if you use `KDE` as desktop environment you can use `kmenuedit` to create desktop files easily.